# does anyone know of good delphi docking components?

Tags: delphi, docking

we'd like to add movable panels to an application.  presently we've used DevExpress docking library but have found them to be disappointingly quirky & difficult to work with.  it also has some limitations that aren't so great.

auto-hide, pinning, and moving of pages by drag-and-drop are all features we'd like to use.

the built-in delphi docking doesn't seem to be full-featured enough to do the things we need (also see sample below).  perhaps i should dig deeper into delphi's docking abilities...my initial impression is that they seem very toolbar-oriented rather than something i can drop a frame into.

i'm not experienced at docking topics.  my only experience has been with the DevExpress docking library where i needed to programmatically create & dock panels.

[image: screenshot]

is it my imagination or are DevExpress's products unduly difficult to use/learn?  the DevExpress Ribbon Bar component compared to the d2009 Ribbon Bar was certainly a useful experience.  i will migrate to the d2009 Ribbon Bar as soon as convenient to do so.  it was refreshingly straight-forward to learn and use.  a sharp contrast compared to the DevExpress equivalent.  if it takes 4x as longer to make it using the DevExpress equivalent, it's time to change direction.

what would *you* suggest in regard to the docking library?

thank you for your suggestions/comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutomatedDocking
http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqdocking/index.asp

and for free one JVCL Docking
http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/

Comment: Please update your bookmarks. It is http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/ since more then a year now.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm not a big fan of docking...but...
Have you played a lot with the docking as it is in Delphi?
If it does all that you want, then give a new try to the VCL...

Answer (score 2):

AutomatedQA's docking components are great. Easy to work with, good help, Visual Studio 2005 style docking hints, etc. I started with DevExpress docking components (I still love DevExpress and use lots of their components), but I think the AutomatedQA docking components are easier to use and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

LMD Innovative has a docking pack (http://www.lmdinnovative.com/products/vcl/lmddockpack/). Didn't use/need the code so far but the compiled examples worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to read your post, I'm using Automated QA' docking components, and I'm fed up with them. I was considering switching to DevExpress, but I think I willl give it a second thought now.
The most problematic with AutomatedQA's component is bugs, sometimes floating windows disappears, when pinned panels are unpinned and stuff like this.

AutomatedQA does not offer a decent support and new releases should not be expected on a yearly basis, even if you have pointed out a bug that can be easily reproduced. I have a suspicion that the docking framework doesn't get much focus within AutomatedQA.

I gues one have to turn to the built in VCL or perhaps JEDI, but I can't find any valuable samples (the mediocre docking sample included with Delphi does not provide much help), but I guess it must be possible, after all they built Delphi using this...

Does anyone know a good JEDI docking sample application?

Comment: There should be one in the demos folder of JVCL.