# How to implement this type of Docking?

Tags: delphi, dock, docking

Take a look at this Open Source Application called [Construct](http://www.scirra.com/construct/)
.

It uses Panel Docking where you can drag a Panel, and then some on screen visual aids to show where the Panel may be docked, as seen below:

**Before Dragging/Docking**

[image]

**During Dragging/Docking stage**

When dragging/moving one of the Dock Panels the Window now looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, when dragging/moving the Object Panel it displays the visual aids of where the Panel can be docked. It also moves around like a free Window when not in a docking position. The same applies when dragging/moving other Dock Panels such as the Project Panel in this example.

This is an example of an Application using this, I have also seen other Applications employ this too.

Is there a Delphi way of acheiving this behaviour?

I have some panels that take up some space, freely moving or docking them would be useful feature to implement.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

It seems the LMD Components offer such a component which I may look into.

Comment: it's been almost a week since the last activity on this question, and no accepted answer.  Can I suggest you check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394289/recommendations-for-a-docking-library-for-delphi-cbuilder) linked by @Neftali below? It examines all docking libraries available for Delphi, and I've been keeping it up to date as things have changed. (Re your update: I personally found the LMD components unreliable, see that question for details.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this [old question for docking library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394289/recommendations-for-a-docking-library-for-delphi-cbuilder).

**[Recommendations for a docking library for Delphi / C++Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394289/recommendations-for-a-docking-library-for-delphi-cbuilder)**

Comment: +1 .The automated QA library has exactly that visual appearance.

Comment: Hey, that's my question!  +1 :)  Btw, it's not very old - as far as I know, its content is still up to date for available releases. Also it looks at every single docking library around for Delphi/C++Builder, so it's a good overview of all options for the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

Why there shouldn't be a way of achiving this in Delphi?

I don't know if there are free components around but DevExpress offers a [library](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExBars/DockingLib.xml) for it and other vedors for sure have such libraries in there portfolio too.

If you're interested in coding such a thing your self, you might take a look at *Dockpanel Suite* it is written in C# but the WinAPI fundementals behind it are the same.

*Addition:*
[does anyone know of good delphi docking components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228115/does-anyone-know-of-good-delphi-docking-components)

Answer (score 4):

There's a new release of the DevExpress docking components coming soon. It includes the Visual Studio style docking that you show in your image.

See this link for more information: http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/ctodx/archive/2011/04/26/sneak-peek-visual-studio-dock-style-for-vcl-docking-library-coming-in-v2011-1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Delphi  supports this out of the box. There's a limited demo (meaning they didn't demonstrate all of the functionality) in the Samples (Demos) folder, depending on which version of Delphi you're using. In Delph7, for instance, it's in `$(DELPHI)\Demos\Docking`, and in D2007 and up you'll find it in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\RAD Studio\x.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32`, where `x.0` refers to the Delphi version. The locations for D2009 and XE will vary if you've installed on Vista or Win7, but I'll trust you can track them down; if you can't, use the Start Menu's `Embarcadero RAD Studio <version>`, and choose `Samples`.

There's also the TDockTabSet component included in later versions of Delphi, and you can find an [article and code](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33446) at Embarcadero Developer Network explaining and demonstrating it's use. (TDockTabSet is pretty much what's used in the IDE for docking now, I believe.)

Comment: -1. `dockex` sample project only showing how problematic out-of-box functionality is. (shown: 2 glitches, not shown: heavy flicker, dragging artifacts, cpu hogging)(http://i.imgur.com/SLN3z.png)

Comment: Delphi only sortof supports it out of the box - there's no widget support (that plus symbol you can drag onto), and it's all a bit clumsy to use. In D2010, at least, it also doesn't drag transparent blue windows, which is surprising since the IDE does.

Comment: Out of the box, Delphi docking support is "vestigial" or "a start", and not complete enough to handle most of what the OP needs.  A third party library is essential, either commercial or open source.

Answer (score 1):

I did a few intro videos on dockable forms in Delphi, there are available [here](http://codegearguru.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=60&Itemid=27) and [here](http://codegearguru.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=61&Itemid=27).  They're also on YouTube - [Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa1SH4u2o3Y), and [Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNT_m1cnK38).  They are pretty introductory however.